# How to select the first h3 (without class or id) inside a div with the .woocommerce-billing-fields class with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The idea is to change the `<h3>`
content when the page loads

```html
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields">
   <h3>Detalhes de faturamento</h3>
   <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
      <p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field" data-priority="10"><label for="billing_first_name" class="">Nome&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value="Brunno" data-qa-id="Nome" autocomplete="given-name"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-last validate-required" id="billing_last_name_field" data-priority="20"><label for="billing_last_name" class="">Sobrenome&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" placeholder="" value="Vert" data-qa-id="Sobrenome" autocomplete="family-name"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-email" id="billing_email_field" data-priority="30"><label for="billing_email" class="">Endereço de e-mail&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="email" class="input-text " name="billing_email" id="billing_email" placeholder="" value="brunnovert98@gmail.com" data-qa-id="Endereço de e-mail" autocomplete="email username"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field update_totals_on_change validate-required" id="billing_country_field" data-priority="40">
         <label for="billing_country" class="">País&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label>
         <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
            <select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select " data-qa-id="País" autocomplete="country" data-placeholder="Selecione um país…">
               <option value="">Selecione um país…</option>
               <option value="AF">Afeganistão</option>
               <option value="ZA">África do Sul</option>
               <option value="AL">Albânia</option>
               <option value="DE">Alemanha</option>
               <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
               <option value="AO">Angola</option>
               <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
               <option value="AQ">Antártica</option>
               <option value="AG">Antígua e Barbuda</option>
               <option value="SA">Arábia Saudita</option>
               <option value="DZ">Argélia</option>
               <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
               <option value="AM">Armênia</option>
               <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
               <option value="AU">Austrália</option>
               <option value="AT">Áustria</option>
               <option value="AZ">Azerbaijão</option>
               <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
               <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
               <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
               <option value="BH">Barém</option>
               <option value="PW">Belau</option>
               <option value="BE">Bélgica</option>
               <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
               <option value="BJ">Benim</option>
               <option value="BM">Bermudas</option>
               <option value="BY">Bielorrússia</option>
               <option value="BO">Bolívia</option>
               <option value="BA">Bósnia e Herzegovina</option>
               <option value="BW">Botsuana</option>
               <option value="BR" selected="selected">Brasil</option>
               <option value="BN">Brunei</option>
               <option value="BG">Bulgária</option>
               <option value="BF">Burquina Fasso</option>
               <option value="BI">Burúndi</option>
               <option value="BT">Butão</option>
               <option value="CV">Cabo Verde</option>
               <option value="CM">Camarões</option>
               <option value="KH">Camboja</option>
               <option value="CA">Canadá</option>
               <option value="QA">Catar</option>
               <option value="KZ">Cazaquistão</option>
               <option value="TD">Chade</option>
               <option value="CL">Chile</option>
               <option value="CN">China</option>
               <option value="CY">Chipre</option>
               <option value="SG">Cingapura</option>
               <option value="CO">Colômbia</option>
               <option value="KM">Comores</option>
               <option value="MP">Comunidade das Ilhas Marianas Setentrionais</option>
               <option value="CG">Congo (Brazzaville)</option>
               <option value="CD">Congo (Kinshasa)</option>
               <option value="KP">Coréia do Norte</option>
               <option value="KR">Coréia do Sul</option>
               <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
               <option value="CI">Costa do Marfim</option>
               <option value="HR">Croácia</option>
               <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
               <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
               <option value="DK">Dinamarca</option>
               <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
               <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
               <option value="EG">Egito</option>
               <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
               <option value="AE">Emirados Árabes Unidos</option>
               <option value="EC">Equador</option>
               <option value="ER">Eritreia</option>
               <option value="SK">Eslováquia</option>
               <option value="SI">Eslovenia</option>
               <option value="ES">Espanha</option>
               <option value="US">Estados Unidos</option>
               <option value="EE">Estônia</option>
               <option value="ET">Etiópia</option>
               <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
               <option value="PH">Filipinas</option>
               <option value="FI">Finlândia</option>
               <option value="FR">França</option>
               <option value="GA">Gabão</option>
               <option value="GM">Gâmbia</option>
               <option value="GH">Gana</option>
               <option value="GE">Geórgia</option>
               <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
               <option value="GD">Granada</option>
               <option value="GR">Grécia</option>
               <option value="GL">Groenlândia</option>
               <option value="GP">Guadalupe</option>
               <option value="GU">Guam</option>
               <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
               <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
               <option value="GY">Guiana</option>
               <option value="GF">Guiana Francesa</option>
               <option value="GN">Guiné</option>
               <option value="GQ">Guiné Equatorial</option>
               <option value="GW">Guiné-Bissau</option>
               <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
               <option value="NL">Holanda</option>
               <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
               <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
               <option value="HU">Hungria</option>
               <option value="YE">Iémen</option>
               <option value="BV">Ilha Bouvet</option>
               <option value="CX">Ilha Christmas</option>
               <option value="HM">Ilha Heard e Ilhas McDonald</option>
               <option value="NF">Ilha Norfolk</option>
               <option value="IM">Ilha de Man</option>
               <option value="MF">Ilha de São Martinho (República Francesa)</option>
               <option value="AX">Ilhas Aland</option>
               <option value="KY">Ilhas Cayman</option>
               <option value="CC">Ilhas Cocos</option>
               <option value="CK">Ilhas Cook</option>
               <option value="FO">Ilhas Feroe</option>
               <option value="GS">Ilhas Geórgia do Sul e Sandwich do Sul</option>
               <option value="FK">Ilhas Malvinas</option>
               <option value="MH">Ilhas Marshall</option>
               <option value="UM">Ilhas Menores Distantes, Estados Unidos da América (EUA)</option>
               <option value="PN">Ilhas Pitcairn</option>
               <option value="SB">Ilhas Salomão</option>
               <option value="TC">Ilhas Turcas e Caicos</option>
               <option value="VI">Ilhas Virgens (EUA)</option>
               <option value="VG">Ilhas Virgens Britânicas</option>
               <option value="IN">Índia</option>
               <option value="ID">Indonésia</option>
               <option value="IR">Irã</option>
               <option value="IQ">Iraque</option>
               <option value="IE">Irlanda</option>
               <option value="IS">Islândia</option>
               <option value="IL">Israel</option>
               <option value="IT">Itália</option>
               <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
               <option value="JP">Japão</option>
               <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
               <option value="JO">Jordânia</option>
               <option value="KW">Kuweit</option>
               <option value="LA">Laos</option>
               <option value="LV">Látvia</option>
               <option value="LS">Lesoto</option>
               <option value="LB">Líbano</option>
               <option value="LR">Libéria</option>
               <option value="LY">Líbia</option>
               <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
               <option value="LT">Lituânia</option>
               <option value="LU">Luxemburgo</option>
               <option value="MO">Macao</option>
               <option value="MK">Macedônia do Norte</option>
               <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
               <option value="MY">Malásia</option>
               <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
               <option value="MV">Maldivas</option>
               <option value="ML">Mali</option>
               <option value="MT">Malta</option>
               <option value="MA">Marrocos</option>
               <option value="MQ">Martinica</option>
               <option value="MU">Maurício</option>
               <option value="MR">Mauritânia</option>
               <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
               <option value="MX">México</option>
               <option value="FM">Micronésia</option>
               <option value="MZ">Moçambique</option>
               <option value="MD">Moldávia</option>
               <option value="MC">Mônaco</option>
               <option value="MN">Mongólia</option>
               <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
               <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
               <option value="NA">Namíbia</option>
               <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
               <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
               <option value="NI">Nicarágua</option>
               <option value="NE">Níger</option>
               <option value="NG">Nigéria</option>
               <option value="NU">Niue</option>
               <option value="NO">Noruega</option>
               <option value="NC">Nova Caledónia</option>
               <option value="NZ">Nova Zelândia</option>
               <option value="OM">Omã</option>
               <option value="BQ">Países baixos Caribenhos</option>
               <option value="PA">Panamá</option>
               <option value="PG">Papua-Nova Guiné</option>
               <option value="PK">Paquistão</option>
               <option value="PY">Paraguai</option>
               <option value="PE">Peru</option>
               <option value="PF">Polinésia Francesa</option>
               <option value="PL">Polônia</option>
               <option value="PR">Porto Rico</option>
               <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
               <option value="KE">Quênia</option>
               <option value="KG">Quirguistão</option>
               <option value="KI">Quiribáti</option>
               <option value="GB">Reino Unido (UK)</option>
               <option value="CZ">República Checa</option>
               <option value="DO">República Dominicana</option>
               <option value="CF">República da África Central</option>
               <option value="MM">República da União de Myanmar</option>
               <option value="RE">Reunião</option>
               <option value="RO">Romênia</option>
               <option value="RW">Ruanda</option>
               <option value="RU">Rússia</option>
               <option value="EH">Saara Ocidental</option>
               <option value="SX">Saint Martin (parte Holandesa)</option>
               <option value="PM">Saint-Pierre e Miquelon</option>
               <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
               <option value="AS">Samoa Americana</option>
               <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
               <option value="SH">Santa Helena</option>
               <option value="LC">Santa Lúcia</option>
               <option value="BL">São Bartolomeu</option>
               <option value="KN">São Cristóvão e Nevis</option>
               <option value="ST">São Tomé e Príncipe</option>
               <option value="VC">São Vicente e Granadinas</option>
               <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
               <option value="SL">Serra Leoa</option>
               <option value="RS">Sérvia</option>
               <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
               <option value="SY">Síria</option>
               <option value="SO">Somália</option>
               <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
               <option value="SZ">Suazilândia</option>
               <option value="SD">Sudão</option>
               <option value="SS">Sudão do Sul</option>
               <option value="SE">Suécia</option>
               <option value="CH">Suiça</option>
               <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
               <option value="SJ">Svalbard e Jan Mayen</option>
               <option value="TH">Tailândia</option>
               <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
               <option value="TJ">Tajiquistão</option>
               <option value="TZ">Tanzânia</option>
               <option value="IO">Território Britânico do Oceano Índico</option>
               <option value="PS">Território Palestino</option>
               <option value="TF">Território das Terras Austrais e Antárcticas Francesas</option>
               <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
               <option value="TG">Togo</option>
               <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
               <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
               <option value="TT">Trinidad e Tobago</option>
               <option value="TN">Tunísia</option>
               <option value="TM">Turcomenistão</option>
               <option value="TR">Turquia</option>
               <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
               <option value="UA">Ucrânia</option>
               <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
               <option value="UY">Uruguai</option>
               <option value="UZ">Uzbequistão</option>
               <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
               <option value="VA">Vaticano</option>
               <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
               <option value="VN">Vietnã</option>
               <option value="WF">Wallis e Futuna</option>
               <option value="ZM">Zâmbia</option>
               <option value="ZW">Zimbábue</option>
            </select>
      <noscript><button type="submit" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="Atualizar país">Atualizar país</button></noscript></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-phone" id="billing_phone_field" data-priority="50"><label for="billing_phone" class="">Telefone&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value="(11) 99664-4255" data-qa-id="Telefone" autocomplete="tel"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required validate-postcode" id="billing_postcode_field" data-priority="60" data-o_class="form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required validate-postcode"><label for="billing_postcode" class="">CEP&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" placeholder="" value="06706-062" data-qa-id="CEP" autocomplete="postal-code"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required woocommerce-validated" id="billing_address_1_field" data-priority="70" style="display: block;"><label for="billing_address_1" class="">Endereço&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_address_1" id="billing_address_1" placeholder="Nome da rua e número da casa" value="Rua Antônio de Camargo" data-qa-id="Endereço" autocomplete="address-line1"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field woocommerce-validated" id="billing_address_2_field" data-priority="80" style="display: block;"><label for="billing_address_2" class="screen-reader-text">Apartamento, suíte, unidade, etc. (opcional)&nbsp;<span class="optional">(opcional)</span></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_address_2" id="billing_address_2" placeholder="Apartamento, suíte, unidade, etc. (opcional)" value="São Paulo II" autocomplete="address-line2"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row validate-required" id="billing_billing_number_field" data-priority="90"><label for="billing_billing_number" class="">Número&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_billing_number" id="billing_billing_number" placeholder="" value="" data-qa-id="Número"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required woocommerce-validated" id="billing_city_field" data-priority="100" data-o_class="form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required" style="display: block;"><label for="billing_city" class="">Cidade&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_city" id="billing_city" placeholder="" value="Cotia" data-qa-id="Cidade" autocomplete="address-level2"></span></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required validate-state woocommerce-validated" id="billing_state_field" data-priority="110" data-o_class="form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required validate-state" style="display: block;">
         <label for="billing_state" class="">Estado&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obrigatório">*</abbr></label>
         <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
            <select name="billing_state" id="billing_state" class="state_select " data-qa-id="Estado" autocomplete="address-level1" data-placeholder="Selecione uma opção…" data-input-classes="">
               <option value="">Selecione uma opção…</option>
               <option value="AC">Acre</option>
               <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
               <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
               <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
               <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
               <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
               <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
               <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
               <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
               <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
               <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
               <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
               <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
               <option value="PA">Pará</option>
               <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
               <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
               <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
               <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
               <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
               <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
               <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
               <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
               <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
               <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
               <option value="SP" selected="selected">São Paulo</option>
               <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
               <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
            </select>
         </span>
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I know it’s not a good practice, but it’s a temporary solution

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.woocommerce-billing-fields > h3:first-child').innerHTML = 'text you want to display';
```

The above code uses vanilla javascript to select the first h3 found within the first container with class `woocommerce-billing-fields`. You can then manipulate its contents by updating its `innerHTML` property.

The syntax of the selector used in `querySelector` matches the same way you would scope that field in CSS. More info on querySelector here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector:
`'.woocommerce-billing-fields > h3:first-of-type'`

The `>` is a child combinator. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the direct children of elements matched by the first. Basically, it looks only at first-level descendants.

The `h3:first-of-type` selects the first element of its type (which in this case is `h3`) among a group of sibling elements.

So the selector `'.woocommerce-billing-fields > h3:first-of-type'` will select amongst the first-level descendants of your containing div (`.woocommerce-billing-fields`), the first `h3` it finds.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type